# Figure size does not correspond to specifications

Tags: pgfplots

I just started to learn pgfplots. I am trying to generate a square plot of my data and I am having trouble to obtain a figure of the correct dimension, which I set as 7 cm x 7cm. pdfinfo indicates that the size is 186.621 x 181.215 pts.

I searched the pgfplots manual and I found the following:
*"pgfplots will try to produce the desired width including
labels, titles and ticks"* - I may be doing something wrong but I also wonder whether this explains this behavior.

Thank you for your help.

Below is my code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}  
\pgfplotsset{width= 7cm, height= 7cm, compat=newest}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]  
\begin{axis}[  
   xlabel=$k$,  
   ylabel={$\beta$},  
   ylabel style=  
    {  
      yshift= -1 mm,   
    },  
    ]
\addplot coordinates {  
    ( 1.5, 1.28 )  
    ( 1.75, 1.43 )  
    ( 2.0, 1.59 )  
    ( 2.25, 1.75 )  
    ( 2.5, 1.91 )  
    ( 2.75, 2.07 )  
    ( 3.0, 2.23 )   
};  

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also check out the `scale only axis` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `pgfplots` in the description for `width` and `height`:

> Please note that pgfplots only estimates the size needed for axis- and
>   tick labels. The estimate assumes a fixed amount of space for anything
>   which is outside of the axis box. This has the effect that the final
>   images may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than the prescribed
>   dimensions. However, the fixed amount is always the same; it is set to `45pt`. ...

Package [`tikzscale`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) solves the problem by setting the `tikzpicture` several times in order to scale it to the desired size without changing the font and line sizes.

The full `tikzpicture` is put in a file and read by `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{tikzpicture01.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]
\begin{axis}[
   xlabel=$k$,
   ylabel={$\beta$},
   ylabel style=
    {
      yshift= -1 mm,
    },
    ]
\addplot coordinates {
    ( 1.5, 1.28 )
    ( 1.75, 1.43 )
    ( 2.0, 1.59 )
    ( 2.25, 1.75 )
    ( 2.5, 1.91 )
    ( 2.75, 2.07 )
    ( 3.0, 2.23 )
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\includegraphics[width=7cm, height=7cm]{tikzpicture01.tikz}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`pdfinfo` reports a nearly perfect square for the size (7cm ≈ 198.4252 bp):

```
Page size:      198.428 x 198.424 pts (rotated 0 degrees)
```

Comment: Thank you! During my searches, I did not come across this package - you helped me a lot.